# Combine and sort using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This VBA code SUMS the values in Column G if they are the same number. I need it to SUM the total regardless.

The items in blue and red are to be combined and their totals summed.
[image]

I get the following
[image]

The items in BLUE worked as intended and the items in RED did not. The items in blue added together because they are the same. I need them to add together no matter.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim fn As String, a, x, s As String, i As Long, n As Long, temp
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSVFiles,*.csv")
    If fn = "False" Then Exit Sub
    x = Split(CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile(fn).ReadAll, vbNewLine)
    ReDim a(1 To UBound(x) + 1, 1 To 1)
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 0 To UBound(x)
            If x(i) <> "" Then
                s = Split(x(i), ",", 2)(1)
                If Not .exists(s) Then
                    .Item(s) = .Count + 1
                    a(.Count, 1) = x(i)
                Else
                    temp = Split(a(.Item(s), 1), ",")
                    temp(0) = temp(0) & Chr(2) & Split(x(i), ",")(0)
                    temp(6) = Val(temp(6)) + Val(Split(x(i), ",")(6))
                    a(.Item(s), 1) = Join(temp, ",")
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    With Cells(1).Resize(UBound(a, 1))
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Value = a
        .TextToColumns .Cells(1), 1, comma:=True
        .Replace Chr(2), ", ", 2
        .CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code doesn't distinguish anything by colour.

Comment: The colors are in the excel chart sorry i wrote this kinda fast

Answer (score 0):

Limit the dictionary key to the 4 fields you want to aggregate on.

```
Sub test()

    Dim fn As String, ts, arCSV, ar, arOut
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, r As Long, iCount As Long
    Dim s As String, key As String, sCanopy As String
    Dim t0 As Single
    
    fn = Application.GetOpenFilename("CSVFiles,*.csv")
    If fn = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
          Set ts = .OpenTextFile(fn)
          s = ts.readall
          ts.Close
    End With
    
    ' split text into array of lines
    t0 = Timer
    arCSV = Split(s, vbNewLine)
    ReDim arOut(1 To UBound(arCSV) + 1, 1 To 1)
    
    n = 0
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
        For i = 0 To UBound(arCSV)
            ar = Split(arCSV(i), ",")
            If UBound(ar) >= 10 Then
                ' 4 key fields Descr,Size,Cut Length, Finish
                key = Trim(ar(3)) & "_" & Trim(ar(4)) & "_" & Trim(ar(7)) & "_" & Trim(ar(10))
                
                sCanopy = ar(0) ' aggregate with comma
                iCount = Val(ar(6)) ' summate
                
                If .Exists(key) Then
                    r = .Item(key)
                    
                    ' modify array
                    ar = Split(arOut(r, 1), ",")
                    
                    ' add canopy if not already in col 0
                    If InStr(ar(0), sCanopy) = 0 Then
                        ar(0) = ar(0) & Chr(2) & sCanopy
                    End If
                    ' total count
                    ar(6) = ar(6) + iCount
                    arOut(r, 1) = Join(ar, ",")
                  
                ElseIf Len(key) > 0 Then
                    n = n + 1
                    .Add key, n
                    arOut(n, 1) = arCSV(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    With Cells(1).Resize(n)
        .CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        .Value = arOut
        .TextToColumns .Cells(1), 1, comma:=True
        .Replace Chr(2), ", ", 2
        .CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    
    MsgBox i - 1 & " rows scanned in " & fn, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    
End Sub
```

CSV Test File

```
CANOPY,B1,PART,DESC,SIZE,,Count,CUT-LEN,,,FINISH
A2,,,BEAM,6x6,,10,71 3/8,,,MF
A2,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,69 3/8,,,MF
B2,,,BEAM,6x6,,4,59 3/8,,,MF
B2,,,BEAM,6x6,,5,89 3/8,,,MF
B2,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,57 3/8,,,MF
A1,,,BEAM,6x6,,12,71 3/8,,,MF
A1,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,69 3/8,,,MF
B1,,,BEAM,6x6,,4,59 3/8,,,MF
B1,,,BEAM,6x6,,5,89 3/8,,,MF
B1,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,57 3/8,,,MF
A4,,,BEAM,6x6,,15,71 3/8,,,MF
A4,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,69 3/8,,,MF
B4,,,BEAM,6x6,,4,59 3/8,,,MF
B4,,,BEAM,6x6,,5,89 3/8,,,MF
B4,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,57 3/8,,,MF
A3,,,BEAM,6x6,,16,71 3/8,,,MF
A3,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,69 3/8,,,MF
B3,,,BEAM,6x6,,4,59 3/8,,,MF
B3,,,BEAM,6x6,,5,89 3/8,,,MF
B3,,,BEAM,6x6,,2,57 3/8,,,MF
```

Comment: This just adds all values in column H together so i get 105 qty instead of the correct qty of 53

Comment: @NikolasMichelini Do you not get 5 lines of output ? Are the counts not in column G

Comment: i get 5 lines of out put and the counts are in column g.

Comment: There are 5 lines of output and the counts are in column G however, using the 71 3/8" pc as an example. There are 53 spread out over 4 canopys (10 in A2, 12 in A1, 15 in A4 and 16 in A3) so what it sould spit out is A1,A2,A3,A4 all in one cell and the count would be 53

Comment: @NikolasMichelini Yes, that's what I get in my output, I have added the csv I used to my answer.